# Advanced RememberProperty pattern

Tags: design-patterns, properties, wix

Rob Mensching has an article ["Remember Property pattern"](https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern) which allows to protect values, specified in command-line from being overwritten by RegSearches. And all works fine until we need some advanced logic (e.g. default values).

I extended that pattern a bit for setting default values with custom actions (still works fine):

```
<Fragment>
  <Property Id="MY_PROPERTY">
    <RegistrySearch Id="MyProperty_RegSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompanyName\MyApplicationName" Name="MyProperty" Type="raw"></RegistrySearch>
  </Property>

  <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
    <Component Id="PermanentRegistryValues" Guid="MY_GUID" Permanent="yes">
      <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompanyName\MyApplicationName" Action="create">
        <RegistryValue Name="MyProperty" Type="string" Value="[MY_PROPERTY]" />
      </RegistryKey>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>

  <CustomAction Id="SaveCmd_MyProperty" Property="cmd_MyProperty" Value="[MY_PROPERTY]" Execute="firstSequence" />
  <CustomAction Id="RestoreCmd_MyProperty" Property="MY_PROPERTY" Value="[cmd_MyProperty]" Execute="firstSequence" />
  <CustomAction Id="SetDefault_MyProperty" Property="MY_PROPERTY" Value="MyPropertyDefaultValue" Execute="firstSequence" />

  <InstallUISequence>
    <Custom Action="SaveCmd_MyProperty" Before="AppSearch" />
    <Custom Action="RestoreCmd_MyProperty" After="AppSearch">cmd_MyProperty</Custom>
    <Custom Action="SetDefault_MyProperty" Before="ValidateProductID">NOT MY_PROPERTY</Custom>
  </InstallUISequence>

  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="SaveCmd_MyProperty" Before="AppSearch" />
    <Custom Action="RestoreCmd_MyProperty" After="AppSearch">cmd_MyProperty</Custom>
    <Custom Action="SetDefault_MyProperty" Before="ValidateProductID">NOT MY_PROPERTY</Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Fragment>
```

**But here is a problem:**

If I need to use MyProperty in RadioButtonGroup for example, WIX (I assume it's in fact MSI limitation) doesn't allow to declare this property with no value set like in example above. Setting some dummy value is also not possible - WIX gives another compilation error:

`error LGHT0204: ICE34: dummy is not a valid default value for the RadioButtonGroup using property MyProperty. The value must be listed as an option in the RadioButtonGroup table.`

I also tried adding 'dummy' option to RadiobuttonGroup and placing that option in coordinates (1000;1000) which are far beyond the borders of RadioButtonGroup control. But the disadvantage is that using keyboard user can select that option. In addition this is definitely a bad practice.

*So my question:* **Is it possible and how to implement Remember property pattern in case I need a default value from a fixed set of allowed values?**

Here is the remaining part of code I'm talking about (hope that will help you):

```
<Property Id="MY_PROPERTY" Value="Value1">
  <RegistrySearch Id="MyProperty_RegSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompanyName\MyApplicationName" Name="MyProperty" Type="raw"></RegistrySearch>
</Property>

<Control Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="MY_PROPERTY" Id="MyRbtn" Width="100" Height="159" X="34" Y="90">
  <RadioButtonGroup Property="MY_PROPERTY">
    <RadioButton Text="Value1" Value="Users" Width="100" Height="17" X="0" Y="0" />
    <RadioButton Text="Value2" Value="Roles" Width="100" Height="17" X="0" Y="45" />
  </RadioButtonGroup>
</Control>
```

**PS:** I tried many combinations of conditions on Restore and SetDefault custom actions, but no of them works in all required cases: install in UI mode / silent mode, upgrade, change / repair.

I don't see any simple way to overcome this. The only possibility is involving one more helper property and doubling the number of custom actions (which is already a lot (3) for single property).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving a Wix checkbox value that defaults to checked to the registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531852/saving-a-wix-checkbox-value-that-defaults-to-checked-to-the-registry) - I posted an example there a while back that covered all edge cases I could find.

Comment: Thanks, that is really close question, but not a duplicate. That question used checkbox control, which allows any values set (including -1 which you used as dummy). I also tried dummy value and I mentioned that in question, but the result was compilation error. Is it possible to solve the problem without dummy values? Or any solution that works with RadioButtonGroup.

Comment: Is it possible to set radio button to invisible?

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I tried this placing control far beyond the screen borders, but that didn't help much - we can check that RadioButton with keyboard. There is no special attribute to disable single RadioButton element if you meant this.