# Storing user-entered data from a Wix installer

Tags: c#, wix, installation, windows-installer, wix-extension

I am creating a **Wix installer** and I would like to store some values that are set by the user during the installation process in such a way that I can read them at a later point in time. Obviously I could save these values in the registry but is there a better way to achieve this in Wix?

Comment: One of the easier ways to write such values to the system is via IniFile entries. You would then need a relatively simple custom action to read the values back.

Comment: One of the brain dead shortcoming to the Windows Installer IMO. Why design the INIFile table to write to an INI file in any directory and yet limit the INILocator table to the Windows directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's so wrong with storing them in the registry?

Seriously :)

I've been in the business for 20+ years and have seen the evolution from Windows 3.1 to Windows 8.1... going back further to Commodore 64 / 128D / CPM / AmigaOS but we won't count that.    I saw the evolution from INI to Registry to XML and personally I think the hatred for the registry was overhyped.  I do dislike COM and COM registration but using the HKLM and HKCU hives to store company / product specific configuration information is just fine and it's wonderfully supported by windows Installer.   It's the XML support that Windows Installer lacks.  To a degree, WiX lacks XML support also as the last time I looked it could write XML data but not read it without additional custom actions.

So if you want a robust, solid installer, just use the registry.

Comment: I've no objection to using the registry at all but I'm new to WiX and I just wanted to ensure I wasn't missing some better option that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this feature. but you should investigate this blog entry from Rob Mensching: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/

Here is another stackoverflow post:
[Advanced RememberProperty pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687298/advanced-rememberproperty-pattern)

Comment: Rob's remember property pattern is lacking IMO.  I've detailed my objections in the past as you want a property value precedence pattern to go along with it for servicing during upgrades.

Comment: I have never tried the pattern. I implemented this "persist property feature" myself in a C++ dll when I did SOE deployment coding. It wrote properties to the registry and read them back with the option of overriding or not.